# How to link directory to public_html?

Tags: apache, directory, ln, public-html

I have ~/public_html and few subdirectories with sites inside. But I have also ~/projects with all my projects (not only websites). I'm trying to link ~/projects/X with ~/public_html/X.

```
ln -s ~/projects/X ~/public_html/X
```

But I have error 403, access forbiden. Directory and files into it have rx rights. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable "FollowSymLinks" option for your public_html folder.

Comment: The problem was, that I didn't checked projects rights. X was 755, but projects don't.